# Ways to reduce Jquery loading time on slow internet connections

Tags: jquery, performance

Many of the users of my website complain about the speed, being that they have a really slow connection.

I've optimized everything I could optimize (js, css, html minification [optimization too] and gzip compression), still the culprit is Jquery as it takes ages to load (tested on a slow connection myself) and sometimes causes a timeout.

I've tried to pack it in a 32-bit png file, that then the client decrypt and retrieve the original file, but still its size is larger than a normal gzipped one, then the cpu load adds up and the page get stuck many times because of that (the decrypting process in the background).

Even with a combination of minification and gzipping it still is a large piece of ass: 21kb.

Now, do you think further optimization like function shortening is possible here? I've tried but it brokes apart, won't work after I do that. Is trying to divide it to several little chunks and then being loaded asynchronously the way? or it will just add up to the problem, having more http requests?

Actually I'm using Drupal with the following modules enabled which maybe are the reason I can't use a custom Jquery build:

- Block
- Comment
- Field
- Field SQL Storage
- Field UI
- File
- Filter
- Image
- Menu
- Node
- Options
- Search
- Syslog
- System
- Taxonomy
- Text
- Update Manager
- Chaos Tools
- Jquery Update
- Views
- Views UI
- Rate
- Voting API

If you found another method please tell me, thanks.

Comment: a) What kind of connection are we talking about that 21k is considered so huge, and b) Why is it an issue after the initial page is loaded, shouldn't the linked script file be cached by the browser?

Comment: @UweB their connection is like ~4/kbpersec if we don't take latency in the cause. The moment it is cached (and that's the second time they visit the website) it's fluid, but first time visitors/users are stuck with horrible page loading time and many other issues as timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The chances of you using the entirety of jQuery are probably quite low, so you could try building a [custom version](http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/) with only the modules that you need.

If that still doesn't help, then try loading jQuery from a [CDN](http://cdnjs.com/). This helps because many developers choose a common CDN provider, which means that copy of jQuery from that CDN will be saved locally more often, resulting in one less download.

Comment: I tried downloading a custom build, but it broke my pages. I use Drupal as a content management system.

Comment: What modules did you use? You may have plugins installed which require certain modules to be included within jQuery.

Comment: these are the modules I am actively using, maybe you can see which are the issue here?:

Block
-
Comment
-
Field
-
Field SQL Storage
-
Field UI
-
File
-
Filter
-
Image
-
Menu
-
Node
-
Options
-
Search
-
Syslog
-
System
-
Taxonomy
-
Text
-
Update Manager
-
Chaos Tools
-
Jquery Update
-
Views
-
Views UI
-
Rate
-
Voting API

Comment: @stackoverloop Please edit your question with that information, it's unreadable in a comment...

Comment: @AlexisPigeon made that into the answaar.